# R: Adding geom_vline labels to geom_histogram labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add the labels to the x-axis for the data from the `geom_vline` layer without having to regenerate the existing ones:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data_frame(x = rnorm(10000)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x)) + 
  geom_histogram(bins = 100) + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(x) + 2.6)) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: @Hack-R x-axis intercept is not labeled for me. I have added the output of  the code for me, and made a small change to the code to make this more discernible.

Answer (score 5):

You could do this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data_frame(x = rnorm(10000)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x)) + 
  geom_histogram(bins = 100) + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(x) + 2.6)) + 
  theme_bw() +
  geom_text(aes(x=mean(x) + 2.6, label="My label text", y=0), colour="blue", angle=90)
```

Comment: Too cumbersome, I have a large list of summary functions that I want to add to my histogram.

Comment: @tchakravarty You could parameterize it then. If you give me an example I can show you.

Comment: Thanks, but I would rather hack the axis label apparatus than trying to get `geom_text` to align with the existing labels for look and feel.